# Отправка данных через всплывающий div (поиск адреса, миновать скрипт)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form, html

Пытаюсь научиться работать со скрытыми формами и разобраться в нюансах.

Поясню проблему:
Есть сайт http://krona-clinic.ru/ (взять для примера) на нем есть кнопка записи, нажимая на нее появляться скрытый див
в коде страницы я его нашел, вот он:

```
<form action="/#wpcf7-f4-o2" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0.1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f4-o2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
    </div>
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Имя" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-47"><input type="text" name="text-47" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Телефон" /></span><br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap message"><input type="text" name="message" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Сообщение" /></span><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
    <input type='hidden' class='wpcf7-pum' value='{"closepopup":false,"closedelay":0,"openpopup":false,"openpopup_id":0}' /><div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

Так же есть ява скрипт http://krona-clinic.ru/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.0.1 по моему это он отвечает за отправку данных (поправьте если ошибся).
В этом скрипте насколько я понял вот это код отвечает за отправку данных:

```
$.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
            '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
        ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
        $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
    } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
        var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
        $form.after( $e );
    } );
};
```

Но я что-то никак не пойму куда отправлять данные (на какой юрл)?
Буду признателен за пояснения, если, где ошибся и за пример на php для отправки данных (как пример по данному сайту).
Спасибо.

отправил запрос

```
$url = 'http://krona-clinic.ru/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4/feedback';
// this is only part of the data you need to sen
$customer_data = array('_wpcf7' => '4',
"_wpcf7_version" => "5.0.1",
"_wpcf7_locale" => "en_US",
"_wpcf7_unit_tag" => "wpcf7-f4-o2",
"_wpcf7_container_post" => "0",
"your-name" => "Иван",
"text-47" => "89999222233",
"message"=>"записаться на прием" 
);
// As per your API, the customer data should be structured this way
// And then encoded as a json string
$data_string = json_encode($customer_data);
$ch=curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array(
        $ch, 
        array( CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string, CURLOPT_HEADER => true, 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

на http://krona-clinic.ru/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4/feedback и получил ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2018 18:59:59 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31 Set-Cookie: vchideactivationmsg=1; expires=Fri, 15-Oct-2021 18:59:59 GMT; Max-Age=94694400; path=/ Set-Cookie: vchideactivationmsg_vc11=5.0.1; expires=Fri, 15-Oct-2021 18:59:59 GMT; Max-Age=94694400; path=/ X-Robots-Tag: noindex Link: ; rel="https://api.w.org/" X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type Allow: POST Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 X-Cache: MISS from t0.hoster.ru X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from t0.hoster.ru:6666 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive {"into":"#","status":"validation_failed","message":"One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.","invalidFields":[{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.your-name","message":"The field is required.","idref":null},{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.text-47","message":"The field is required.","idref":null},{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.message","message":"The field is required.","idref":null}]
```

Comment: На тот URL где у вас обработчик данных формы написан.

Comment: Простите. Может я что-то не понял. Это не мой сайт. Мне и нужно найти юрл куда отправлять запрос, это один из вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Окей. Открываем консоль разработчика в браузере. Пишем туда пару вещей:

```
var form = jQuery( 'div.wpcf7 > form' )[0]
wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
            '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( form ) + '/feedback' )
```

И получаем:

```
 "http://krona-clinic.ru/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/4/feedback"
```

Это один из способов, что первым в голову забрел.

Comment: т.е. это юрл куда нужно отправлять данные? При открытии данного юрла выдает: {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u0445\u043e\u0434\u044f\u0449\u0438\u0439 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442 \u0434\u043b\u044f URL \u0438 \u043c\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d","data":{"status":404}}

Comment: Ну я так думаю его не просто так надо открывать, а делать POST запрос и передавать данные. А вообще - черт его знает что там на бэкенде в этом сайте - гадать и тыкать палкой можно долго. Вам вообще зачем?

Comment: Есть много сайтом как этот (оставить заявку и т.д.) у всех реализация аналогичная как я посмотрел. Вот и хочу научиться как это реализовывать... Сам разобраться не могу, вот и спросил совета. Хочу потом прикрутить заявку отправлять через свой сайт.

Comment: Ну это какой-то Wordpres-way, роутеры эти - по мне так усложнение на ровном месте, но тем не менее гораздо эффективнее Вам поднять у себя демку на вордпрессе и идти курить вордпрессовскую документацию по формам. То чем вы занимаетесь сейчас - иначе как вырыванием гланд через задний проход не назовешь.

Comment: Добавил ответы в вопрос. Что-то не так с полями видно...

Comment: Конечно, там поля обязательные, их надо передавать POST запросом

Comment: $customer_data = array('_wpcf7' => '4',
    "_wpcf7_version" => "5.0.1",
    "_wpcf7_locale" => "en_US",
    "_wpcf7_unit_tag" => "wpcf7-f4-o2",
    "_wpcf7_container_post" => "0",
    "your-name" => "Иван",
    "text-47" => "89999222233",
    "message"=>"записаться на прием" 
    );    Что я упустил из полей?

Comment: Смотрите форму - там все теги `input` - в том числе скрытые - типа `pum_form_popup_id` - в них обычно какое-то зафиксированное значение - его целиком берете из value.